# Terminated after 5 months, should I add it to a resume?

Tags: resume, termination

I'm FOR SURE being terminated from an "at will" position on Thursday.  Things didn't work out on both sides.  They expected more out of me, and I of them.
(I was told I would be mentored, which apparently meant letting me flounder and figure out a NEW system I'd never heard of all on my own for a month and then two weeks of one hour meetings).

**That aside, I spent 5 months in this position and I am wondering, even though it is less than 6 months, since it's the only position I had, I need to add it to my resume, right?**

Comment: I believe these comprise two separate questions. Why not post them separately?

Comment: No use posting the second question separately. It is off-topic here. I'm going to edit it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add this to your resume because it is the only position you have had. I would add it even it wasn't the only position that you had.

You have a hole in your resume. You may feel that just skipping it makes sense, but then you are presenting yourself as somebody who hasn't worked before. If you do get as far as an interview they will ask you about any positions you may have had, even if you didn't get paid. Now you will have to tell them that I was employed by X for 5 months but decided to try and hide it. You might use better words but that is what they will hear.

You should always expect that they will ask why you left a position. And it is good to have a well crafted truthful response. But purposefully avoiding mentioning a position just throws suspicion on the accuracy of your resume.

Question #2 is related to your local laws, local custom, and your contract.